# How open files with Peg.js?

Tags: javascript, parsing, compiler-construction, peg

How can I read the file within my language?

I am trying to understand how languages ​​work. I would like to know how to create a simple grammar to read files using `Peg.js`.
In Python it is something like this

```
f= open("testfile.txt","w+")
```

**Grammar Example in Peg.js**

```
{
   var keywords = ["f=", "open"];
}

Expression =
    word:$(Word) { return { word: word } } /
    keyword:$(Keyword) { return { keyword: keyword } }

// Word will match everything except "f" and "open"
Word = word:$([a-zA-Z]+) &{ return !keywords.includes(word) }

Keyword = [a-zA-Z]+

start
  = f open symbol

open
  = attribute:',"w+"'? __ { return write; }
  = attribute:'include'? __ { return include; }

include
  = include : "'_ exp:[a-zA-Z]+ _'" _ { return include; }

symbol
  = '("' _ exp:[a-zA-Z]+ _ '")' { return [ exp.join('') ]; }

// optional whitespace
_  = [ \t\r\n]*

// mandatory whitespace
__ = [ \t\r\n]+
```

But I get this error:

> Line 21, column 3: Expected "/", ";", comment, end of input, end of line, identifier, or whitespace but "=" found.

Sample: **Peg.js**

```
f= open("testfile.txt","w+")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the syntax error because your definition of `open` contains two `=`s. I assume you want the second one to be a `/` instead. Then `open` would match either the string `,"w+"` (or nothing) or `include`.

That's not the only issue in your code though. Here are some others I've noticed:

- Your first three rules and the other rules don't use each other. So if you're using `Expression` as your start rule (the default as it comes first), only the first three rules will matter. And if you use `start` as the start rule, the first three rules won't matter at all.
- You list `"f="` in your array of keywords and then check whether a string matching `[a-zA-Z]+` is inside that array. But `f=` does not match that pattern, so having it in the array is pointless.
- You define `start` as `f open symbol`, but `f` isn't defined anywhere.
- `"'_ exp:[a-zA-Z]+ _'"` matches the literal string `'_ exp:[a-zA-Z]+ _'`. That is almost certainly not what you want.